# Java: Atomic tuple of integers

Tags: java, multithreading

I was wondering if I can somehow implement an atomic tuple of 3 integers without using a synchronized block.

I guess one way would be to encode the 3 ints to an atomic long, each taking 21 bits, but that might break if the code ever requires more than 3 ints.

So what would be the java goto implementation on this case?

Comment: Why avoid the `synchronized` block? (Or method modifier?)

Comment: You meant AtomicLong, I think.

Comment: There is no built in atomic double.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the tuple immutable, and use an AtomicReference.

```
public static class ThreeInts {
    private final int first;
    private final int second;
    private final int third;
    ...
}

AtomicReference<ThreeInts> threeInts = new AtomicReference<>(someDefault);
```

and then to update, it'd be something like:

```
while (true) {
    ThreeInts current = threeInts.get();
    ThreeInts next = somehowEvaluateNew(current);
    if (threeInts.compareAndSet(current, next) {
        break;
    }
}
```

You could also use just an `int[]` instead of the class. The downside there is that the `int[]` isn't immutable (and can't be made immutable). So, either you have to hide it behind some abstraction like an `UnmodifiableIntArray`, or you need to make it absolutely clear to all users of this code that the `int[]` may not be modified once it's put into the atomic reference. This obviously requires some trust on your part, so you should be careful with it; but it's an option.

If you don't mind autoboxing, you could also use a `Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(i0, i1, i2))` as a replacement for `ThreeInts`.

Comment: You could use an `int[]` for any number of `int` values.

Comment: For that matter, can't you do it with any object, that just implements equals correctly?

Comment: @DzmitryPaulenka AtomicReference.compareAndSet uses reference equality, not `equals`.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the point to use this ThreeInts than? how would you recreate reference to pass to `compareAndSet`?

Comment: Sorry, I get it now.

Comment: @yshavit One might also use AtomicReference's getAndUpdate or updateAndGet, passing 'somehowEvaluateNew' as parameter.

Comment: @JonasN Yes, that's true. If the new values don't depend on the old values, you can even just do a `set` and leave it at that!